# Eclipse Create Remote Project returns "Internal Error: Connection not found for host:null"

Tags: eclipse

I've configured an **SSH Only** remote system using **RSE**. It seams to be connected properly and I can view the files in **Remote Systems** tab under

```
<system name>/Sftp Files/Root/
```

If I select **Create Remote Project** from the context menu of a directory in the remote system, the following error message is displayed:

> Internal Error: Connection not found for host:null

Eclipse log shows the following informational message:

> ENTRY org.eclipse.rse.core 1 0 2016-06-01 11:41:03.691
>   MESSAGE Saved passwords are not available for migration to secure storage. Deprecated authorization classes (org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.auth) are not installed.

### Environment

- **Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.**
- **Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)**